# Let $D:= \{1/n:n \in\mathbb N_+\} \cup\{0\}$ and $f: D\to \mathbb R$ be any function. Show that $f$ is continuous at $1/n$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $D:= \{1/n: n \in\mathbb N_+\} \cup\{0\}$ and $f: D \to \mathbb R$ be any function. Show that $f$ is continuous at $1/n$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

I didn't understand what it means by saying continuous at $1/n$. can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The concept of continuity at a point is introduced in every book on Calculus.

Comment: How will I show that the function is continuous at 1/n for every natural number n

Comment: $|x-\frac 1 n| <\delta\equiv \frac 1 {n(n+1)}, x \in D$ implies $x=\frac  1n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $x\in D$ if for all open $U$ with $f(x)\in U$ there is open $V\subseteq D$, $x\in V$, with $f[V]\subseteq U$. For your specific choice of $D$, the points $1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are isolated, that is $\{1/n\}$ is open, so $V = \{1/n\}$ always works. So, more generally, any function is continuous at an isolated point.

Comment: You may find this article helpful even if it's long.
https://mathforums.com/t/doubt-about-continuity-and-accumulation-points-with-value-of-limit.355714/